# Unexpected "arguments" property on object

Tags: javascript

In the following, the second and third console outputs seem to contradict:

```
function test() {

    console.log(arguments); // -> ["my", "arguments"]

    console.dir(this); // -> test function with arguments property set to null

    console.log(this.arguments); // -> ["my", "arguments"]

}

test.call(test, 'my', 'arguments');
```

As per my comments, inspecting the `arguments` property on `this` shows `null`, whilst logging `this.arguments` explicitly shows `["my", "arguments"]`.

What exactly is `this` when you invoke a function in such a way? I didn't expect `this.arguments` to contain the invocation arguments!

Comment: Note that you reproduce the same thing by logging `test.arguments`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

> `arguments` as a property of `Function` can no longer be used.

Therefore I wouldn't attempt to use `this.arguments` at all, but use the local function variable `arguments`.  It's quite apparent that there's some magic going on to create `arguments` as well.

Comment: Thanks! It's not as brain-achy as it first seemed. Declaring `function test() { console.dir(test.arguments); }` and calling `test('my', 'arguments');` shows the depreciated function property without the confusion of contexts :)

Answer (score 5):

> What exactly is this when you invoke a function in such a way? I didn't expect this.arguments to contain the invocation arguments!

The [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) indeed refers to the `test` function - that's what you [`call`ed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) it with. You can assert that by logging `this === test`.

So what's that `arguments` property? A [very deprecated one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments) that is set to the actual [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) during a function invocation (and removed thereafter, which seems to be the reason why `console.dir` didn't capture it correctly). Don't use it, and don't care about it :-)

```
function test() {
    console.assert(this === test);
    console.assert(this.arguments === arguments);
    console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, "arguments"));
}
test.call(test, 'my', 'arguments');

// result (in Opera):
Object {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    value: Arguments {
        0: "my",
        1: "arguments",
        callee: Function {…},
        length: 2
    },
    writable: false
}
```

Comment: Great detailed answer! I'm afraid Explosion Pills just beat you to the punch :)